# Getting 401 response in google developer api only when query voided purchases

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase, google-oauth, android-billing

I'm using Google Play Android Developer API. I access it from a server with service account. I have a private key and got an access token with it.

I use scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher exactly https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/archive/v2/purchases/voidedpurchases/list. And when I ask subscription info, I got 401 error:

```
"Error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "permissionDenied",
    "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
}
 ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
}
```

What could be the cause of the problem? I added this service account to the developer console and provided all permissions (administrator access).

[image]

Comment: Did you find the issue?